# ruby on rails best_in_place nomethoderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

i am getting an error with the best_in_place gem.

i want to edit my comments inside of the post show action since i render all comments there.

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing undefined method `erererer' for #<Comment:0x00007fc0ff1721c8>
```

comment view that i render in posts show page.

```
<!--<h3>there are <%#= pluralize(@comments.count, "comment") %></h3> -->
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<div class="media mb-5 ">
  <% if comment.user.avatar.present? %>
  <%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url, class: 'rounded mr-3 d-flex', width: 42, height: 42%>
    <% else %>
    <%= random_avatar 42, "d-flex rounded mr-3"%>
    <% end %>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between" />
      <h5 class="mt-0"><a><%=link_to comment.user.username, user_path(comment.user)  %></a></h5>

      <p class="m-0 form-group">created at <%=time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></p>
  </div>
  <%= best_in_place comment, comment.body, :as => :textarea %>
  <% if current_user == comment.user %>
  <span style="font-size: 15px;">
    <%= link_to '', [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "sure?"}, class: ' btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm pull-right fa fa-trash-o' %>
    <%= link_to '',edit_post_comment_path(comment.post, comment), class: 'btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm pull-right fa fa-pencil-square-o' %>
  </span>
  <% end %>


</div>
  </div>
  </section>
<%end%>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Activating Best In Place */
    $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
});
```

comments_controller.rb

```
  def update

    if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:body))
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.json { respond_with_bip(@comment) }
    end
  end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 240 }
```

post.controller - add post controller code to question

class PostsController < ApplicationController

```
before_action :find_post, only: %i[destroy edit update comment_owner upvote downvote]
  after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :create, :new]

  layout '_app_nav'

  def index
    return redirect_to post_path(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
    return redirect_to user_path(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
    @post = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @user = User.all
    @posts = if params[:search]

             else
               Post.all.order('created_at DESC')

             end
    @comments = Comment.all

  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new

  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    authorize @post
    if @post.save!
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @user = @post.user
    @comments = Comment.where(post_id: @post).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  end

  def edit
    authorize @post
  end

  def update
    authorize @post

    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_path
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
end

def find_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

UPDATE

This is the entire request that i get when trying to open posts#show

```
Started GET "/news/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-30 03:12:49 +0200
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering posts/show.html.erb within layouts/_app_nav
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (27.1ms)
  Comment Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 2 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 5], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (14.2ms)
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/_app_nav (442.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 509ms (ActiveRecord: 12.4ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `erererer' for #<Comment:0x00007feba5717bc0>):
    15:
    16:           <p class="m-0 form-group">created at <%=time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></p>
    17:       </div>
    18:       <%= best_in_place comment, comment.body, :as => :textarea %>
    19:       <% if current_user == comment.user %>
    20:       <span style="font-size: 15px;">
    21:         <%= link_to '', [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "sure?"}, class: ' btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm pull-right fa fa-trash-o' %>

app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_comments__comment_html_erb___2232672375721569353_70325032812060'
app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_comments__comment_html_erb___2232672375721569353_70325032812060'
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:76:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb___2994099099531367002_70324990819000'
```

Comment: Somewhere you're calling `erererer` on comment. Do a find/replace for `erererer` and remove it.

Comment: i am not colling erererer somewhere..

Comment: You may not be on purpose but that's 100% indicative of what your error is describing.

Comment: I've search my complete directory for erererer and didn't find a single line expect for dev logs

Comment: Is your code on Github somewhere? I can take a peak.

Comment: It isn't, it's on Bitbucket as a private repo

Comment: I have credentials in there because of the dev process atm, so I really can't add anyone right now. What code do you need? I can update the question

Comment: Drop in the entirety of comment.rb and post.rb. ps. don't store your credentials in git

Comment: updated my question. yes, you are correct and i usually don't do this, just a bad timeing right now. sorry for that, would've made it easier

Comment: can you also provide the entirety of posts_controller.rb?

Comment: also try restarting your Rails server. It probably won't matter but you may have booted it and that `erererer` string got caught in something that isn't being reloaded.

Comment: added post controller to question, restarting my server wont fix the problem

Comment: In your Rails console type in `Comment.new` – does it behave as expected?

Comment: Yes it does. results in => #<Comment id: nil, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, post_id: nil, user_id: nil>

Comment: Can you copy-paste the entire stacktrace when you get the error?

Comment: Do you have a `Comment` record with a `body` of `erererer `?

Comment: Oh gosh, now i see where this is going. indeed, i have a record with the body of ererer - so i think the way i want to call for best_in_link is wrong.

Comment: that was a fun one. see my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= best_in_place comment, comment.body, :as => :textarea %>` should be `<%= best_in_place comment, :body, :as => :textarea %>`

Comment: Okay, we figured that out now. Thank you for that! But still something is messed up - undefined method `comment_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f86d2d93cc0>:0x00007f86d2d5b3e8> is what I am recieving with this code.

Comment: You'll need to add the `url` option after `:as => :textarea` like `:as => :textarea, :url => post_comment_path` or whatever the route is.

Comment: <%= best_in_place [@post, comment], :body, :as => :textarea %> this did it as well. thanks for helping me out with this one!